# Select last timestamp (record) for each group on table

Tags: php, mysql

I've passed through some questions here in Stack Overflow, but after some tests it's was not possible to solve my problem.
I have a table like below.

```
  ID           log_device_id           device_timestamp
=========================================================
  1456              0056              2019-05-19 11:45:18
  1451              0061              2019-05-19 22:00:03
  1450              0035              2019-05-19 17:16:23
  1449              0011              2019-05-19 12:31:34
  1448              0124              2019-05-18 09:11:27
```

I'm using the code below to get the Device ID list and timestamp;

```
sql ='SELECT log_device_id,max(device_timestamp) FROM devicetable group by log_device_id';
    $result = mysqli_query($conection, $sql);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['log_device_id'];
            echo $row['device_timestamp'];
            }
```

The problem is, the result of this query returns the ID and Last Timestamp, but the `$row['device_timestamp']`, comes empty and shows a 500 error.

The intention of this code is to check every hour the last timestamp of each device and check if it's is offline.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
sql ='SELECT log_device_id,max(device_timestamp) as max_device_timestamp FROM devicetable group by log_device_id';
$result = mysqli_query($conection, $sql);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['log_device_id'];
        echo $row['max_device_timestamp'];
        }
```

You set alias for max(device_timestamp) then you get value of it

Comment: why this is so? what if we don't give alias?

Comment: Thank you! If I execute the query in the phpmyadmin I got all the devices, but in code it's only return one device. Maybe some problem on ```mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0``` that doesn't count the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql ='SELECT log_device_id, device_timestamp FROM devicetable WHERE device_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(device_timestamp) FROM devicetable) group by log_device_id';
$result = mysqli_query($conection, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['log_device_id'];
        echo $row['device_timestamp'];
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will work for you.
Thank You.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm getting this error: ```Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.tb_log_device.device_timestamp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by```